# why is document.getElementById() not working in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

why is document.getElementById() not working in VS Code?? I keep getting this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: document is not defined".  I'm new to VS Code but I'm assuming the reason It's not working is that I need to install some extension to make it work.  The same code is working on Replit but not VS code. I installed JS(ES6) Snippets, Open-in browser, Live Preview and Live Server. It's very simple 2-line code just to experiment but it's not working. It's driving me crazy!

```js
let head = document.getElementById('change')
head.innerText = 'hello'
```

Comment: you are gonna get more errors if the text you want to apply to your innerText includes quotes like the word `isn't`

Comment: I don't think this is exactly the problem you're trying to solve, but the apostrophe of the `isn't` in `'why isn't this working'` is ending the string early; you should use quotes `"` on the outside or escape the apostrophe with a backslash

Comment: (1) The code shown has a syntax error and won't "work" *anywhere*.  (2) When you get that error message, how are you *running* this code?  If you're running this as a NodeJS process then `document` indeed is not defined.  Because if you're not in the context of a web browser then what "document" are you expecting to interact with and why?

Comment: When your color scheme is off, you know something is screwed up. It's the `isn't` ..Either wrap it in double quotes  or use a backslash to escape that apostrophe. [Decent Explanation about Excaping](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/what-are-string-escape-characters-964401ae94ca)

Comment: I'm sorry! I just wrote 'why isn't this working?' for the purpose of this question.  My actual code just has the word 'hello' set to innerText

Comment: NodeJS does not have a `document`

Comment: why do you add an example that does not reproduce the problem and contains syntax errors, just use dummy strings that do not have syntax errors. A HTML file with these 2 lines is not a valid HTML file

Answer (score 1):

I bet that you are not running this in an index.html file in the browser, so this is not VS Code problem, you are probably running this in a node console or something, there is no html or document in what you are trying to test and that is why you are getting this error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>HELLO</h1>
<hr />
<h2 id="change"></h2>
<script>
    let head = document.getElementById('change')
    head.innerText = "why isn't this working?";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i edited my answer, you had a problem with string concatenation

Answer (score 1):

Definitely has nothing to do with VS Code.

Make sure your html file is referencing your javascript file.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>This is my HTML file</h1>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The script element should be in your html with the name of your js file

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: omg i feel so stupid‍♂️!  I completely forgot to link js to html. Sorry everyone

Comment: @Nir No need to feel stupid my guy! These are the mistakes that help you become a better developer along with a better problem solver.

Answer (score 0):

This not the vscode issue please check you are running the right file